# Pull Metadata from Outlook to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to pull metadata for metric tracking (times sent) from my sent items mailbox.

I'm getting an error

> The attempted operation failed. An Object could not be found.

I've tried several different codes but can not pull any email data from Outlook.

I have ensured that the Outlook 2016 and Excel 2016 objects are active under references.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Inbox").Folders("Sent_Items")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
    Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
    Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
    Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
    Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body

    i = i + 1
End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: When I select Debug, it highlights the

    Sub GetFromOutlook ()

It was also highlighting the Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder line.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try using : Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Sent_Items")

Comment: Its giving me a "Compile error: User-Defined type not defined" and its highlighting the Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Appliation line in blue and highlighting the Sub GetFromOutlook() line in yellow.

Comment: This error comes when the reference is not set. Go to Tools -> References and add the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 reference.

Comment: The outlook references are activated, its still showing the error. I will add that I'm trying to pull data out of my sent items folder sent from a shared mailbox.

Comment: Ohkay, if it's a shared folder then -> 

OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderSentMail)  <- should be used. I have explained the usage more in my updated answer. Please check and confirm, if it's working now.

Comment: Would you clarify whether the sent mail ends up your default mailbox Sent items or the shared mailbox's Sent Items.

Comment: The emails are directly available in my sent items folder, their only being sent out with the from field being generated as a shared mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code from Excel/VBA and it worked perfectly. There is only 1 line of code that gave me error and hence I changed that. It was where you establish reference to the sent items folder.

In the code below, default "Sent Items" folder being used as defined in outlook reference model.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFromOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim OutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set OutlookRecip = OutlookNamespace .CreateRecipient("RobEmail@StackOverflow.com") '// Owner's Email / Shared Folder email address
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(OutlookRecip, olFolderSentMail)

    'If you want to refer to Sent Items folder then use this.
    'Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    ' Or if your Sent Email folder is inside the Inbox then use the line below (Just Uncomment the below and Comment the upper one)
    'Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Sent_Items")

    i = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
            Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
            Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
            Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next OutlookMail

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

However, if your "Sent Items" folder is under "Inbox" or customised then run the code below to get its exact name and then use it.

```
For Each Folder In OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
    Debug.Print Folder.Name
Next
```

Also, below is the comprehensive list of available folders in the Outlook library. Thought would be helpful to you.

[image: Outlook Folders Reference Library List (olFolder)]

Comment: I tried the 

    For Each Folder In     OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
    Debug.Print Folder.Name
    Next
Which resulted in a 424 object required